# Right Axis warps on 3D planet's equator

Tags: 3d, javascript, matrix, planet

I am using JavaScript and WebGL for a game which rotates a spaceship around a 3D planet. Below is the code for rotating a sphere spaceship and sphere planet. I looked over your camera code and now it finally makes sense. Also I found a function in the physics engine I am using for converting a 3x3 Matrix to Euler. I have the three axes for the 3x3 Matrix but I don't know how to find the answer for the x axis.

```
// The side axis that needs to change
this.rightAxis = [1,0,0];
// the planet to ship up axis
let point = vec3Subtract(this.shipPosition, this.planetPosition);
this.upAxis = vec3Normalize(point);
// Moving Direction
this.forwardAxis = vec3CrossProduct(this.rightAxis, this.upAxis);
// Normalized ship velocity when the keyboard is pressed
this.shipVelocity = vec3MultiplyScalar(this.forwardAxis, this.keyboardForwardBackward);
// Find position change
this.shipPosition = vec3Add(this.shipPosition, vec3MultiplyScalar(this.shipVelocity, timeStep));
```

Where rightAxis is x axis, upAxis is y axis, and forwardAxis is z axis. How do I find the correct direction for the x axis when rotating the y axis especially when I am not at the y axis poles?

Comment: Sounds a lot like gimbal lock. How are you modifying shipAngle?

Comment: You may also be interested in [How do I fix my planet-facing camera](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/73670/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for the link. I will look into it asap. I modified the code in my question so the variables including shipAngle are better explained.

Comment: Oh... you really can't add up Euler angles like that and expect a sensible result. Your increment is not even a sensible Euler angle triplet. Your problem is not the use of the right vector, it's that you're computing your angles in a way that is geometrically meaningless. Try taking a step back and explaining the behaviour you want the ship to have — how it's controlled or how it should respond to various game events. Then we can propose better ways of updating its orientation to support that behaviour.

Comment: I tried moving angles with the keyboard then converting them from Polar to Cartesian coordinates but the orientation of the spaceship is crazy. Next I will try raytracing and raymarching physics. @DMGregory I will keep trying. If you have any ideas they are much appreciated.

Comment: My idea is what I stated above: edit your question to describe the gameplay behaviour / input response you want, then we can help suggest ways to achieve it. If you don't define the desired behaviour, we can only guess.

Comment: @DMGregory I have been working on this problem again and I tried my best to rewrite the question. In short, I want to rotate around a sphere the same way games rotate on a flat plane but with a sphere's arc.

Comment: @DMGregory thank you for your planet-facing camera post. I am starting to understand this. If you could answer my questions above I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You still have not followed the directions I gave you in January.

Comment: @DMGregory I finally figured out how to get a rotation matrix working from your replies on the planet-facing camera thread. I wrote it in JavaScript and WebGL on GitHub https://github.com/TigerFusion/SDF-Planets . Thanks for the help. I hope this can help people (like me) to understand how to create a Super Mario Galaxy game.

Comment: Want to post your solution as an Answer below? It's 100% OK to answer your own questions on this site.